# Dynamic class method parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing EventBus in typescript and want to make dynamic parameter `event` in method `emit`. How can I do what?

```
interface IEventBusListener {
  (...params: any[]): void
}

class EventBus {
  constructor(private listeners: Record<string | symbol, IEventBusListener[]> = {}) { }

  on(event: string | symbol, callback: IEventBusListener) {
    if (!this.listeners[event]) {
      this.listeners[event] = [];
    }

    this.listeners[event].push(callback);
  }

  off(event: string | symbol, callback: IEventBusListener) {
    if (!this.listeners[event]) {
      throw new Error(`Нет события: ${event.toString()}`);
    }

    this.listeners[event] = this.listeners[event].filter(
      listener => listener !== callback
    );
  }

  emit<T extends keyof typeof this.listeners>(event: T, ...args: any[]) {
    if (!this.listeners[event]) {
      throw new Event(`Нет события: ${event.toString()}`);
    }

    this.listeners[event].forEach(listener => {
      listener(...args);
    });
  }
}
```

I'll expect auto complete and type check, but it don't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should define the relations map between event name and callback parameters. Like this:

```
class EventEmitter<T extends Record<string, any[]>> {
    on<E extends keyof T>(eventName: E, callback: (...args: T[E]) => void) {
        // ...
    }
}

type ChildMap = {
    'foo': [number]
    'baz': [string]
}
class Child extends  EventEmitter<ChildMap> {

}

const child = new Child();
```

Or use **eventemitter3** library